# Python(MySQL Connector): Fetch real time data and update the variable

Tags: python, mysql

I have a MySQL DB which contains more than 20 million records, now I'm developing a dashboard with dash and plotly. I want to continuously update the data to the dash server as and how new data is entered in my DB. I have read many articles but failed to come across something that can solve my problem of continuously updating records with new data. I'm using read_sql function of dataframe to read records from DB to pandas dataframe.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you're struggling with? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Either you need to regularly poll the mysql database for fresh data or you need to implement some kind of a notification system in python leaving mysql out to notify of the changes.

Comment: @AMC I want to automatically update my dataframe with new records as and when they come to mysql DB

Comment: @NikhilKumarSingh That is what you're trying to accomplish, not a problem or obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it. I have to say though that my solution is rather dirty, but since I also couldn't find any clean solution this might help you.
I used dash_core_components.Interval component. You can basically define a frequency in which your python dashboard is updated by a callback function. The most important part is that you reconnect to your database every time the callback function is called. Otherwise you will not get live data.
My callback function looks sth like this:

```
data = [""]

@app.callback(
    [
    Output("placeholder", "children")
    ],
    [
    Input(component_id = "interval-component", component_property= "n_intervals" )
    ],
    [
    State("placeholder", "children")
    ]
)
def update_container(n_intervals, old_output):
    global data
  
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="admin",
    passwd= "admin",
    database = "database"
    )
    mycursor = db.cursor()

    mycursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    tmp = mycursor.fetchone()
    
    if tmp != data:
        print ("new entry found")
        data = tmp
        return [old_output + [html.Br()] + [html.Div(str(data))]]
    else:
        print ("no new data")
        return [old_output]
```

I get the latest entry in my database table called table and check if it is similar to the one I got before. This way I always get a new entry if one is written in the database. This is the dash component you need for automated updating:

```
html.Div(dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*300, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0))
```